# How do i apply json.loads towards every json file in a directory

Tags: python, json, list, file, directory

I would like to know how to apply: json.loads- towards every json file in a directory.

1) i have tried using json.loads with every file separately however there must be a better way of doing it.

2) i tried using .join, however this only prints out the list of files, not the contents of the json files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Iterate over a list of file-paths, then use json.load?

Comment: "i have tried using json.loads with every file separately however there must be a better way of doing it." Show the actual code you used for this, and then we can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

in python3.7

```
from pathlib import Path
import json 

def load_json_from_dir(path_to_directory):
    all_datas = []
    p = Path(path_to_directory)
    for d in p.iterdir():
        if d.is_file():
            js_data = json.load(d.open())
            all_datas.append(js_data)
    return all_datas
```

or as generator

```
def load_json_from_dir(path_to_directory):
    yield
    p = Path(path_to_directory)
    for d in p.iterdir():
        if d.is_file():
            js_data = json.load(d.open())
            yield js_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to do this with a single generator expression

```
(json.load(open(f)) for _, _, fs in os.walk('somepath') for f in fs if f.endswith('.json'))
```

This will load json files at `somepath` folder. Just change the `somepath` to something that is useful to you.